# how to use both AND or OR conditions in django while filtering

Tags: django, filter

i want to make filter system where if the user selects both year and month then students belonging only to this year's month should be displayed and if the user selects only year then all the students belonging to that year should be displayed.This code works if i select both year and month but doesnot work as OR condition.How can i solve this

> views.py

```
def serachstudent(request):
    year = request.GET['year']
    month = request.GET['month']
    if year or month:
        students = Student.objects.filter(Q(joined_date__year=year) | Q(joined_date__month=month))
        return render(request, "students/view_students.html", {'students': students})
    elif year and month:
        students = Student.objects.filter(Q(joined_date__year=year) & Q(joined_date__month=month))
        return render(request, "students/view_students.html", {'students': students})
```

> template

```
<form action="{% url 'students:search_student' %}" class='form-inline'>
          <!--<label for="month"></label>-->
          <select name="year">
            <option disabled selected>Select Year</option>
            <option value="2018">2018</option>
             <option value="2017">2017</option>
            <option value="2019">2019</option>
          </select>
          <!--<label for="month"></label>-->
          <select name="month">
            <option disabled selected>Select month</option>
            <option value="01">January</option>
            <option value="02">February</option>
             <option value="03">March</option>
            <option value="04">April</option>
            <option value="05">May</option>
            <option value="06">June</option>
             <option value="07">July</option>
            <option value="08">August</option>
             <option value="09">September</option>
            <option value="10">October</option>
             <option value="11">November</option>
            <option value="12">Decembery</option>

          </select>

     &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit" >Find Students</button>
                    </div>

      </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will throw `KeyError` if either month or year isn't specified in the request body.

Change these lines

```
year = request.GET['year']
month = request.GET['month']
```

to

```
year = request.GET.get('year')
month = request.GET.get('month')
```

That way, if they are not specified they will default to `None` and your remaining code should work.

Comment: hey svrw can you please give me some idea to display the years in dropdown template using for loop or any

Comment: You can't do that in the template directly. However, you can define `{'year_list': range(2017, 2019)}` in your view, then render it in the the template with `{% for year in year_list %}`.

Comment: yes it worked .Thank you.can i use datetime.datetime.date something like this within a range

Comment: Yes absolutely.

Comment: `datetime.today().year`

Answer (score 0):

```
if request.GET['year']: year_query = Q(joined_date__year=int(request.GET['year'])
else : year_query = Q()
if request.GET['month']: month_query = Q(joined_date__month=int(request.GET['month'])
else : month_query = Q()

query = Q(month_query | year_query)
students = Student.objects.filter(query)
```